# Searching for files in Vista?

Tags: windows-vista, search

How do you search for files that include "@" in the filename from the search window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Vista:

- press Win+F to show search window
- open Advanced search
- select Location (for example Local Hard Drives)
- type * @ * in Name field (without spaces between * and @)
- to narrow search to files select Document in Show only:
- press Search

Alternatively you can just type following into search box in Windows explorer:

```
name:*@* kind:docs
```

Comment: You might also have to tick the tick box: **´Include non-indexed, hidden, and system files (might be slow)´**

Comment: Nice hint. I was actually needing that. :D

Answer (score 0):

my guess would be to escape it like you would at a command prompt with a caret. e.g.
dir *^@.txt

i don't have a machine to try this on right now.

-don

Answer (score 0):

Much like with most search engines, you can use **" "** [quotation marks].
Not perfect, it will still will find other things (not sure why).
Moreover wildcards will be a bit of a problem.

You can narrow it down to files by using "kind:" (docs, music etc'), you can find some syntax help [here](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/products/winfamily/desktopsearch/technicalresources/advquery.mspx).

[image]

By the way, this is in Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Best app for file searches I've found is "Everything" - and it's lightning fast.
Available  at http://www.voidtools.com/
Makes the Windows search look like steam driven.